# Background color of area surrounding ggplot in a {xaringan} slide

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, xaringan

I'm trying to match the background color of a ggplot with the background color of the slide in a {xaringan} presentation.
But there are some areas that I don't know how to change the color of.
I don't even know if that is controlled by ggplot or by xaringan.

The area I'm talking about is this marked in the image below:
[area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jRyr.png)

I've added borders to the ggplot (red) and the output of the r code chunk (orange) so to delimitate better the area I'm talking about.
To reproduce this behavior you can run the code below:

````
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
institute: "RStudio, PBC"
date: "2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{css, echo = FALSE}
.remark-slide-content {
  background-color: #bfc7e0;
}
```

# Get Started

```{r, echo=FALSE, out.extra = 'style="border:2px solid orange;"'}
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = mpg, y = qsec)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#bfc7e0", colour = "red")) +
  coord_fixed()
```
````

I have no idea where to change the color of these areas, since I've already chenged the background color of the slide and the overall background of the ggplot.

Comment: You can figure some of this out be looking closely at the plot and your parameters. You have set the color for the slide and the background for the plot to be the same, which the appear to be. And you have set the colour to red, which you can see, you have a red border around the plot, but not the white bounding box. As this is the plot.background, then you are probably safe assuming that the white space is caused by the area defined by the document into which ggplot is placed. I would start with figuring out how to size the image space

Comment: Also if you tag this with #xaringan the creator will help you understand how to proceed.

Comment: For the record, this was cross-posted at https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/371.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing special about `xaringan`. The issue is that you use `coord_fixed` but also arises when using `coord_polar` or `coord_sf`.

As a result the plot is rendered with a fixed aspect ratio which means that the size of the plot will not adjust to the size of the plotting device, e.g. you run into the same issue when running

```
library(tidyverse)

png("foo.png")
mtcars %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = mpg, y = qsec)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#bfc7e0", colour = "red")) +
  coord_fixed()
dev.off()
```

[image]

To get rid of the "white" background you could set the background color of the plotting device using `knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev.args = list(bg = "#bfc7e0"))`.

**EDIT** Thanks to the comment by @YihuiXie I think the best option would be to use `"transparent"` for both the background fill of the device and the ggplot. Doing so allows to change the background fill for the slides without the need to change the bg fill color of the device or the ggplot.

````
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
institute: "RStudio, PBC"
date: "2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
library(tidyverse)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev.args = list(bg = "transparent"))
```

```{css, echo = FALSE}
.remark-slide-content {
  background-color: #bfc7e0;
}
```

# Get Started

```{r, echo=FALSE, out.extra = 'style="border:2px solid orange;"'}
mtcars %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = mpg, y = qsec)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = "red")) +
  coord_fixed()
```
````

[image]

Comment: I think `transparent` might be better than a specific color (e.g., if you decide to change the background color of slides, `transparent` will still work): https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/371.

Comment: Thanks @YihuiXie You are absolutely right. Using `transparent` is the best choice. Would suggest to use `transparent` even for the the ggplot bg fill.